# Round up numbers

Tags: php

I get some numbers from database. I would like round up these numbers this way:

```
Database => Round up number
34 => 0
89 => 100
421 => 400
561 => 600
4421 => 4000
6701 => 7000
45000 => 50000
91000 => 90000
132000 => 130000
```

Is there any php function to do this? So numbers under 1000 would be round up closest full 100. Over thousands would be rounded up to nearest full 1000 figure. And if number is over 10 000 then it would be always rounded up to closest full 10 000.

Hopefully you understand what I'm after.

Comment: You've looked at PHP's `round()` function, and seen that it has a `precision` argument?

Comment: I assume you've looked at the manual, right? Specifically, this example direct from the manual: `echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000`

Comment: To add, the `precision` argument will need to vary with the size of your input. Something like `if( $number < 1000) $precision = -2; elseif( $number < 10000) $precision = -3; else $precision = -4;`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it can be calculated no need for ifs. Check my answer.

Comment: @Robert Pay attention to the question!

Comment: The last value seems like an irregularity `132000 => 130000` shouldn't it be `100000`? Update: Oh I see, I missed the closest 100 part

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm fed up of people *not reading the damn question*...

```
function myRound(int $number) : int {
    // remove typehints if you're on old versions of PHP...
    $magnitude = abs($number);
    if( $magnitude < 1000) $precision = -2;
    elseif( $magnitude < 10000) $precision = -3;
    else $precision = -4;

    return round($number,$precision);
}
```

[IDEOne test](https://ideone.com/HdTo8p)

Comment: I'd love to hear why this was downvoted. Go ahead. Entertain me :)

Comment: IDK, but I'm guessing the off-topic attitude. Sorry for poor entertainment value, LOL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `round()` function here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

and the `ceil()` function here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Something like

```
$number = 1;
$number = ceil($number / 10) * 10;

echo $number;
```

Comment: And how would you use these functions here?

Comment: Example code doesn't come close to working like OP asked for. It rounds `89` to `90`, not the requested `100`.

Comment: The question was "is there a function in php",  the answer is yes

Comment: The answer's "no" actually. There is no function to round in this precise way. A user-defined function will be making use of `round`, sure, but it will need to do some additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple math(mostly to calc num length) and build in with negative precision [round()](http://php.net/round) function

```
 function customRound($number) {
    return round($number,  -floor(log10($number)));
 }

 echo customRound(6701); // sample of usage
```

`-floor(log10($number))` this part is to calc length of num - 1 and also it is negated for round() needs

Comment: This rounds `132000` to `100000`, not the `130000` OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
$number = 45000;

function rounder($num) 
{
    $length = strlen($num);
    if(is_int($num))
    {
        if($num < 100)
            return round($num, -($length));
        elseif($num < 1000  || $num <= 9999)
            return round($num, -($length-1));
        else
            return round($num, -4);
    }
}

echo rounder($number);
```

Though not tested, should work..

Comment: This takes `89` and gives `90`, not the `100` OP is asking for.

Comment: Nope. `132000` rounds to `100000`, not the requested `130000`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol calm down.. ;P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101388/discussion-between-niet-the-dark-absol-and-sagar-guhe).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
$numbers = [
    34,
    89,
    421,
    561,
    4421,
    6701,
    45000,
    91000,
    132000
];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $len = strlen((string)$number);
    $precision = $len - 1;
    $precision = $len <= 2 ? 2 : $precision;
    $precision = $len > 4 ? 4 : $precision;
    echo $number . ' => '. round($number, -1 * $precision) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
34 => 0
89 => 100
421 => 400
561 => 600
4421 => 4000
6701 => 7000
45000 => 50000
91000 => 90000
132000 => 130000
```